# Debugging is not working in Qt creator 4.0.2

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, qt-creator

I have installed a new Qt Creator recently (4.0.2) and have faced with the issue that debugging stoped working:
I put breakpoint in main and it isn't being hit.
I build in debug mode & run in debug.
I have gcc installed and Qt creator have found gdb from it.

When I start application from Qt creator in debugging mode I got:

```
Debugging starts
Debugging has finished
```

When I use gdb and start it from command line, gdb finds debugging symbols and everything works fine.

I have stumbled upon that latest versions of Qt creator requires python extensions:

> "Starting with version 3.1, Qt Creator requires the Python scripting
>   extension. GDB builds without Python scripting are not supported
>   anymore and will not work. The minimum supported version is GDB 7.5
>   using Python version 2.7, or 3.3, or newer."

but I haven't find any directions how to use/install that extensions.